# Using Vanilla JS to update page content dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, dynamic, data-manipulation

Good day all

So I am working on a project that is essentially an old school pen & paper rpg that runs off a chatroom.  Ive hit a wall though because each characters skills and stats are based on their attributes, and while the initial value is established I need to find a way to make the stats and skills update dynamically when they adjust these attributes.  I know this is probably a cinch for Angular, but I figure the less moving parts the less likely it is that it will fail.

Essentially the goal is to set the JS up so that when the attributes are updated so are the skills and stats.  Here's the code so far for the attributes:

```
 <td colspan="2">MEMORY</td>
    <td colspan="2">     
    <button onclick="decMem();" class="modButton" type="button">-</button>   
    <input type="text" id="MEM" class="trait" readonly /><script>document.getElementById("MEM").setAttribute('value', Mem);</script>
    <button onclick="incMem();" class="modButton" type="button">+</button>
  </td>

function incMem(){
if (traitPts > 0 && Mem < 20){
traitMod += 1;
Mem += 1;
traitPts -= 1;
document.getElementById("MEM").setAttribute('value', Mem);
document.getElementById("traitPts").setAttribute('value', traitPts);
} else { alert("CAN'T INCREASE FURTHER");}}

function decMem(){
if (traitMod > 0 && Mem > mem){
traitMod -= 1;
Mem -= 1;
traitPts += 1;
document.getElementById("MEM").setAttribute('value', Mem);
document.getElementById("traitPts").setAttribute('value', traitPts);
} else { alert("CAN'T REDUCE FURTHER");}}
```

And then each of the stats or skills is determined by variables like so:

```
//COMBAT STATS
var seq =   Math.floor((Per + Spd) / 2);
var act =   Math.floor(Spd / 2);
var block = Math.floor((Dex + Spd) / 2);
var dodge = Math.floor((Dex + Spd) / 4);

//UNIVERSAL SKILLS
var stealth =   (Per * 3) + Dex;
var climb =     (Dex * 3) + Str;
var negot =     Cha * 4;
var navig =     (Log * 2) + Per + Mem;
```

and sent to the page like this:

```
<td>STEALTH</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="stealth" readonly/><script>document.getElementById("stealth").setAttribute('value', stealth);</script></td>
  <td>CLIMBING</td>
  <td><input type="text" id="climb" readonly /><script>document.getElementById("climb").setAttribute('value', climb);</script></td>
```

The thing is if I do a page reload all the attributes will change as its set up to simulate dice rolls so I'm at a loss here.  But this is a PHP page, so maybe there's a way to temporarily store the data?  Please help!

Comment: Do you understand the difference between code running in the browser (javascript) and code running on the server (php)? Because you *could* store those stats in the server using php, or you *could* store them in a cookie on the browser.

Comment: Use [localstorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Storage)

Comment: Ok so I can set up one page to have the user mod their attributes, and then another to give the final output of their skills / stats.  Is there any way to do this all on the same page?

Comment: Im really more interested in knocking out the whole character creation bit on one page

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple options for doing with with Javascript and maintaining the variables across a refresh. If you'd like the information to be cleared at the end of a browsing session, you can use `sessionStorage`, but if you'd like it to stay available to your application indefinitely you can use `localStorage`. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage) for the docs.

Basically, what you'll do to "save" the data in the browser is:

```
localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
// or
sessionStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

Then to get the data out later, you will use

```
var cat = localStorage.getItem('myCat');
```

Which, in this case, would return the value `'Tom'`

Comment: Ok so I can set up one page to have the user mod their attributes, and then another to give the final output of their skills / stats.  Is there any way to do this all on the same page?

Comment: Im really more interested in knocking out the whole character creation bit on one page

Comment: If you can do this separately on two pages, I would think it is only easier to do it on one. What specifically are you asking?

Comment: What I would like to happen is for all of the stats and skills that are dependent on the attributes to update as soon as the incMem(); or decMem(); functions are called